# Confused about passport.use(strategy) done function and it's relation with passport.authenticate

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

I have a few questions regarding how passport.js works. On it's documentation theres an axample:

```
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

And from [this](http://toon.io/understanding-passportjs-authentication-flow/) article I read:

> Calling done will make the flow jump back into passport.authenticate.
> It's passed the error, user and additional info object (if defined).

So the questions are (and hope they make sense):

1. Where is the done function defined?
2. How when and where is it passed as an argument to function(username,
   password, done)?
3. How is passport.use(new LocalStrategy()) connected to
   passport.authenticate? The quotation says one call the other, but I
   can't see where that is happening

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass your `done()` function as an argument when you call `passport.authenticate()`. The time you call it, your strategy is called too and passes the function you defined as 3d argument.

**Visual Flow**

```
function done(err, user, info) => {
  if (err || !user) {
    return new Error(info.msg);
  }

  // log-in user
}

// pass done
passport.authenticate("local", done); 
              │                 └┬──→ will be called within LocalStrategy
              │                  │    e.g. if (!user) done(err, user, info);
              ↓                  │
  calls your strategy func       │
                 └───┐           └───────────────┐
                     ↓                           ↓           
new LocalStrategy(function (username, password, done) {
  User.findOne({ username}, (err, user) => {     │
    if (!user) {                                 │
      return done(err, user, { mgs: "err" });  ←─┤
    }                                            │
  });                                            ↓
});                                   here done func is called
```

If it is not what you want to know, clarify your question then, please.

**UPDATE:**

As it has been already mentioned, `callback` is optional parameter in `passport.authenticate()`. If you pass it — this function is wrapped by [verified(default)](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/4d9fbefeba48164c43d5bde4e48ff57c2c37d372/lib/strategy.js#L80) one which becomes the 3d argument within your strategy. The time you call this wrapping function there, it verifies parameters you sent and decides the response type: `success`, `fail`, or `error` — all these methods are created [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/0b3931330e245d8e8851328a7dc436433d6411c9/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L192) and call [your custom](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/0b3931330e245d8e8851328a7dc436433d6411c9/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L193) `done()` function(if exists). If it isn't supplied `passport` handles authorization automatically then.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I really appreciate it. just to make it clear, in this case you have supplied a custom done function. There is an example in passport docs, this one: 

`passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/',failureRedirect: '/login' }));`

then the question is, in this case, where is done defined? or more broadly, where is the default done function defined on the source code?

Comment: Guess it's to be found here somewhere https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/0b3931330e245d8e8851328a7dc436433d6411c9/lib/middleware/authenticate.js#L171

Comment: Ok. Yeah, I have to make a remark: `done()` function is wrapped by `verified()` function(which is default one, as you say) — https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/4d9fbefeba48164c43d5bde4e48ff57c2c37d372/lib/strategy.js#L80 — which is your `done()` func in your strategy: `(username, password, done) =>{ ... }`. So if you do not specify custom callback, then user's authorization, establishing a session become automatic. I will try to describe the whole process of their relation later.

Comment: I've updated my post now. I hope I correctly understood your need...

Comment: Thanks again for your reply and thorough update Leonardo!